# How can I install software packages to an Ubuntu system with no internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I have two Ubuntu systems, neither has any internet access.  One has some software installed (via apt) which I would like to install on the other system.  How can I do this?  I have a USB stick I can use.

Answer (score 3):

you can copy necessary deb files to your target machine and run from cmd line:

```
dpkg -i /mnt/usbStick/package1.deb  /mnt/usbStick/package2.deb ...
```

find your dependencies at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ; eg for mc and latest ubuntu it would be: http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/mc

Answer (score 1):

On the first machine where you have internet access you can run such spell:

```
dpkg -l
```

It will give you list of all packages installed on the first machine.
You can use

```
apt-get -d packag_name
```

to download only the package on the forst machine (on Debian apt store by default all packages here : /var/cache/apt/archives/ probably Ubuntu too).

Than u can copy all necessery packages to yout USB stick and install on the second machne
using this command:

```
$dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

This is the most easiest way to do that.
If somethin is unclear please let me know. I can give you morwe details.

--
Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu also includes several utilities that can assist in maintaining package installations and updates for offline machines.  Look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline for a starting point.  Several resources are available for both command line and GUI utilities.

Answer (score 0):

On the machine where the SW is installed (call it the "first" machine), check /var/cache/apt/archives for the packages (ending in .deb) you want to copy.  It's sounds as if it's not certain they're still cached, so it may be you don't find anything in there, or not the packages you want to install on the second machine.

For those packages you do find, copy them to the memory stick, and then install them on the second machine with dpkg... my fore-posters have already covered that bit.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to make use of dpkg-repack if you do not still have the .debs cached in /var/cache.

you'll need to install it on one of your machines, but it is a very tiny package that you can easily copy over on a usb drive...

http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/all/dpkg-repack/download

once installed on your machine with packages, you can use it to recreate a .deb file from packages you have installed.